# How to pass variables in spark SQL, using SparkR?

Tags: sql, variables, sparkr

I am new in SparkR. I am trying to write a query on a dataset using SparkR using Qubole Notebook. several process taken but not getting the output.

Data: Table_A

```
ID      Name     month      year
1        A         2        2020
2        B         2        2019
3        c        12        2019
```

Desired Output:

```
ID      Name     month      year
1        A         2        2020
```

[image]

Variables:

```
month_value= 2
year_value = 2020
```

## Process 1:

```
temp_data = sql("
select * 
from Table_A
where month = $month_value and year = $year_value")
```

## Process 2:

```
temp_data = sql(s"
select * 
from Table_A
where month = $month_value and year = $year_value")
```

## Process 3:

```
temp_data = sql("
select * 
from Table_A
where month = {0} and year = {1}".format(month_value,year_value))
```

## Process 4:

```
temp_data = sql("
select * 
from Table_A
where month = ${month_value} and year = ${year_value}")
```

How to pass the variables in spark SQL, using SparkR?

Answer (score 0):

The **filtering** can be done using the `where` clause in the `sql` function or using the `filter` function directly.

Setup with sample data:

```
library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))
sparkR.session(master = "local[*]", sparkConfig = list(spark.driver.memory = "8g"))

local_df <- data.frame(ID=c(1, 2 ,3),
                       Name=c("A", "B", "c"),
                       month=c(2, 2, 12), 
                       year=c(2020, 2019, 2019))

month_value <- 2
year_value <- 2020

sdf <- createDataFrame(local_df)
```

First approach using `sql`. Create the temp view from the SparkDataFrame named `sdf`. Then you can use `glue` to compose the sql code. It is a string interpolator which is cleaner than using `paste`.

```
# 1) SQL function (string interpolation)
createOrReplaceTempView(sdf, "Table_A")
(sql_expanded <- as.character(glue::glue(
  "select * from Table_A where (month == {month_value}) and (year == {year_value})")))
head(sql(sql_expanded))
```

The result:

```
> (sql_expanded <- glue::glue(
+   "select * from Table_A where (month == {month_value}) and (year == {year_value})"))
select * from Table_A where (month == 2) and (year == 2020)
> head(sql(as.character(sql_expanded)))
  ID Name month year
1  1    A     2 2020
```

The second option, using `filter`

```
> head(filter(sdf, sdf$month == month_value & sdf$year == year_value))
  ID Name month year
1  1    A     2 2020
```